# Chrome zooming in on screen touch (like Android does) on Windows 8 touchscreen

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, touchscreen, zoom

I just noticed this "feature" today and I absolutely hate it. On my phone it's a great idea - on my laptop it's awful.

Basically, when tapping on objects with a small hitbox, like the checkboxes in Google Keep or the X in the Chrome console, the screen will zoom in and require you to tap it again:

[image: zoom issue]

Is there any way to get rid of this? Has anyone else noticed this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically searched the whole internet and came back to it being a google update issue. I'm no professional, so I'm only saying what worked for me. I went to google help under Google Chrome settings. I ended up clearing my browsing and cache, then reset my browser settings under advanced settings. It seems to have worked so far. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I just cleared my cache and cookies and it fixed it.